# How can I condense this printf that uses ANSI colors?

Tags: c, colors, printf, ansi-escape

I am programming a game of Tetris to be played in the terminal. Of course, it wouldn't be Tetris without fancy colors! Unfortunately, to print pretty colors, the code must look ugly. There are ["ANSI escape sequences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) I have used to create colors, and the title screen of my program looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HalT.png). However, to create this beautiful screen, I want to make the code look as neat as possible.

So far I have devised two ways of condensing this code: **definitions** and **strings**. Here is the version of the code that uses **definitions**:

```
#define TEXT_ADMIN "\e[31m"
#define TEXT_ORANGE "\e[38;5;202m"
#define TEXT_BROWN "\e[38;5;130m"
#define TEXT_YELLOW "\e[93m"
#define TEXT_PUKE "\e[33m"
#define TEXT_LIME "\e[92m"
#define TEXT_GREEN "\e[32m"
#define TEXT_AQUA "\e[96m"
#define TEXT_SKY "\e[94m"
#define TEXT_MAGENTA "\e[35m"
#define COLOR_RESET "\e[0m"

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char space[]="        ";

    printf(
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"████████╗"TEXT_ORANGE"███████"TEXT_BROWN"╗"TEXT_YELLOW"████████"TEXT_PUKE"╗"TEXT_LIME"██████"TEXT_GREEN"╗"TEXT_AQUA" ██"TEXT_SKY"╗"TEXT_MAGENTA"███████╗"COLOR_RESET"\n"
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"╚══██╔══╝"TEXT_ORANGE"██"TEXT_BROWN"╔════╝"TEXT_PUKE"╚══"TEXT_YELLOW"██"TEXT_PUKE"╔══╝"TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"╔══"TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_LIME"╗"TEXT_AQUA"██"TEXT_SKY"║"TEXT_MAGENTA"██╔════╝"COLOR_RESET"\n"
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"   ██║   "TEXT_ORANGE"█████"TEXT_BROWN"╗     "TEXT_YELLOW"██"TEXT_PUKE"║   "TEXT_LIME"██████"TEXT_GREEN"╔╝"TEXT_AQUA"██"TEXT_SKY"║"TEXT_MAGENTA"███████╗"COLOR_RESET"\n"
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"   ██║   "TEXT_ORANGE"██"TEXT_BROWN"╔══╝     "TEXT_YELLOW"██"TEXT_PUKE"║   "TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"╔══"TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"╗"TEXT_AQUA"██"TEXT_SKY"║"TEXT_MAGENTA"╚════██║"COLOR_RESET"\n"
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"   ██║   "TEXT_ORANGE"███████"TEXT_BROWN"╗   "TEXT_YELLOW"██"TEXT_PUKE"║   "TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"║  "TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"║"TEXT_AQUA"██"TEXT_SKY"║"TEXT_MAGENTA"███████║"COLOR_RESET"\n"
    "%s"TEXT_ADMIN"   ╚═╝   "TEXT_BROWN"╚══════╝   "TEXT_PUKE"╚═╝   "TEXT_GREEN"╚═╝  ╚═╝"TEXT_SKY"╚═╝"TEXT_MAGENTA"╚══════╝"COLOR_RESET"\n\n"
    "%s             PRESS ANY KEY TO BEGIN\n\n",
    space,space,space,space,space,space,space);

}//TETRIS = 6 lines, text = 1 line, 8 lines total including space.
```

(An ugly monstrosity requiring much horizontal scrolling)

And here is the version which uses **strings**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char admin[]="\e[31m";
    char orange[]="\e[38;5;202m";
    char brown[]="\e[38;5;130m";
    char yellow[]="\e[93m";
    char puke[]="\e[33m";
    char lime[]="\e[92m";
    char green[]="\e[32m";
    char aqua[]="\e[96m";
    char sky[]="\e[94m";
    char magenta[]="\e[35m";
    char reset[]="\e[0m";
    char space[]="        ";

    printf(
    "%s%s████████╗%s███████%s╗%s████████%s╗%s██████%s╗%s ██%s╗%s███████╗%s\n"
    "%s%s╚══██╔══╝%s██%s╔════╝%s╚══%s██%s╔══╝%s██%s╔══%s██%s╗%s██%s║%s██╔════╝%s\n"
    "%s%s   ██║   %s█████%s╗     %s██%s║   %s██████%s╔╝%s██%s║%s███████╗%s\n"
    "%s%s   ██║   %s██%s╔══╝     %s██%s║   %s██%s╔══%s██%s╗%s██%s║%s╚════██║%s\n"
    "%s%s   ██║   %s███████%s╗   %s██%s║   %s██%s║  %s██%s║%s██%s║%s███████║%s\n"
    "%s%s   ╚═╝   %s╚══════╝   %s╚═╝   %s╚═╝  ╚═╝%s╚═╝%s╚══════╝%s\n\n"
    
    "%s             PRESS ANY KEY TO BEGIN\n\n",
    space,admin,orange,brown,yellow,puke,lime,green,sky,blue,magenta,reset,
    space,admin,orange,brown,puke,yellow,puke,lime,green,lime,green,sky,blue,magenta,reset,
    space,admin,orange,brown,yellow,puke,lime,green,sky,blue,magenta,reset,
    space,admin,orange,brown,yellow,puke,lime,green,lime,green,sky,blue,magenta,reset,
    space,admin,orange,brown,yellow,puke,lime,green,lime,green,sky,blue,magenta,reset,
    space,admin,brown,puke,green,blue,magenta,reset,
    space);

}//TETRIS = 6 lines, text = 1 line, 8 lines total including space.
```

As you can see, the string method looks somewhat cleaner, even though it uses more lines and memory, but even this method is quite long. Have I condensed this bit of code as much as I can? Is it even worth it to condense this? Thanks for your input!

Comment: `"You can"         "put any number of spaces between \"\""`. Overall, it's an odd requirement. If it's just for printing one welcome string, just write it once, so it works and displays what you want, call is a function and forget about it. Making the code look "beautiful" is an admirable goal, but in this case is there really a point?

Comment: The first way is easier to read/understand/maintain.  "TEXT_ORANGE" is clear; "\e[38;5;202m" no so much.

Comment: @Andrew true but both substitute the unreadable for the readable. See that I use %s to use a string

Comment: `TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_GREEN"╔══"TEXT_LIME"██"TEXT_LIME"╗"` looks wrong.  2 LIMEs in a row.  How correct are the `printf()`s?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with:

```
// colors.h
#define COLOR_ADMIN   "\033[31m"
#define COLOR_ORANGE  "\033[38;5;202m"
#define COLOR_BROWN   "\033[38;5;130m"
#define COLOR_YELLOW  "\033[93m"
#define COLOR_PUKE    "\033[33m"
#define COLOR_LIME    "\033[92m"
#define COLOR_GREEN   "\033[32m"
#define COLOR_AQUA    "\033[96m"
#define COLOR_SKY     "\033[94m"
#define COLOR_MAGENTA "\033[35m"
#define COLOR_RESET   "\033[0m"

// welcometext.c
#include "colors.h"

#define PRE "        "
#define T COLOR_ADMIN
#define E COLOR_ORANGE
#define e COLOR_BROWN
#define T2 COLOR_YELLOW
#define t2 COLOR_PUKE
#define RC COLOR_GREEN
#define rc COLOR_AQUA
#define I COLOR_SKY
#define i COLOR_AQUA
#define S COLOR_MAGENTA
#define POST COLOR_RESET"\n"

const char welcomestring[] = 
    PRE T "████████╗"   E "███████"e "╗"  T2"███"  "█████"t2"╗"   RC"██████"rc"╗ "          I"██"i"╗"  S"███████╗" POST
    PRE T "╚══██╔══╝"   E "██"e "╔════╝"  t2"╚══"T2"██"t2"╔══╝"   RC"██"rc"╔══"RC"██"rc"╗"  I"██"i"║"  S"██╔════╝" POST
    PRE T "   ██║   "   E "█████"e "╗  "    "   "T2"██"t2"║   "   RC"██████"rc"╔╝"          I"██"i"║"  S"███████╗" POST
    PRE T "   ██║   "   E "██"e "╔══╝  "    "   "T2"██"t2"║   "   RC"██"rc"╔══"RC"██"rc"╗"  I"██"i"║"  S"╚════██║" POST
    PRE T "   ██║   "   E "███████"e "╗"    "   "T2"██"t2"║   "   RC"██"rc"║  "RC"██"rc"║"  I"██"i"║"  S"███████║" POST
    PRE T "   ╚═╝   "   e "╚══════"  "╝"    "   "t2"╚═"  "╝   "   rc"╚═╝  ╚═╝"              i"╚═" "╝"  S"╚══════╝" POST
    "\n"
    PRE  "             PRESS ANY KEY TO BEGIN\n"
    "\n"
    ;

//  welcometext.h
extern const char welcomestring[];

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", welcomestring);
}
```

Note that `L"string"`, `u"string"` and `U"string"` have meaning in C, and `R"string"` is interpreted by GCC as a raw string literal, so I renamed it `RC`. It would be good to pick unique names for defines, to name these single letters something more unique, or add more spaces.

Comment: Is there a technique for writing pretty code like this? Was it elbow grease until everything aligned?

Comment: `Is there a technique for writing pretty code like this?` Spacebar! Also backspace. `Was it elbow grease until everything aligned?` Yes, I did that manually.